# How to increase the max_result_window in elasticsearch using a python script?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-2.6, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I know, we can use the curl to increase the max_result_window as something like:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/index1/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 500000} }'
```

But How do I do the same using python?

My code

```
es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])

res = es.search(index="index1", doc_type="log",size=10000, from_=0, body={ "query": {
....query starts
}})
```

**My question is how,do I change the setting for max_result_window  here**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use [put_settings](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_settings) method.

```
es.indices.put_settings(index="index1",
                        body= {"index" : {
                                "max_result_window" : 500000
                              }})
```

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Thanks for the help Chintan

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution but I got an error. Anyone see this comment, could you check quickly [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266899/adding-percolator-settings-and-mapping-with-python)?

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is searching for a [ElasticSearch Ruby solution](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby), what worked for me on ES version 5 was:

```
es.indices.put_settings(body: {index: {max_result_window: 500000}})
```