# Increase max result window in elasticsearch for ALL indexes in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

There is an already answered question: [How to increase the max_result_window in elasticsearch using a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184200/how-to-increase-the-max-result-window-in-elasticsearch-using-a-python-script)

I am looking for a way to apply this `max_result_window` to all of the indexes. How to achieve that? What I tried (which didn't work):

```
.indices.put_settings(body= {"max_result_window" : 500000})
.indices.put_settings(body= {{"max_result_window" : 500000}})
.indices.put_settings(index="*",
                        body= {"*" : {
                                "max_result_window" : 500000
                              }})
.indices.put_settings(index="all",
                        body= {"all" : {
                                "max_result_window" : 500000
                              }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just was able to make it work. The correct query is the following:

```
es.indices.put_settings(index="_all",body= {"max_result_window" : 500000})
```